# TileMap's Cell Size property is not adjusting the grid of the tile map

Tags: 2d, game-development, godot

I'm creating a simple 2d game using the [Godot engine](https://godotengine.org/). I'm having trouble with the `TileMap` object. Here's what my Scene Tab looks like.

[image]

A `Scene_One` node is the parent of a single child `TileMap` node. When I click on the TileMap node, the Inspector window opens up:

[image: TileMap Inspector Window]

By default, the values of the Cell properties are `64` x, `64` y. My sprite is is too small for the grid. Here's a good look at the problem.

[image: Sprites are smaller than the tileset grid]

My images are smaller than what I assume is a 64 x 64 grid. [I don't know if this assumtion is correct.] So, I adjust the values of the Cell size properties in the Inspector for the TileSet to be (16, 16). Now it looks like this:

[image]

I save, hit Enter, but when I open up the TileSet Editor, *nothing seems to have changed*. I've tried this with different combinations of values for `x` and `y`, but can't seem to adjust the TileSet grid size.

[image: Grid size probelm]

I am a beginner Godot. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong? It's driving me crazy.

Edit: I've tried re-importing `tileset.png` without a filter, same result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to diferenciate between the cell size of the tilemap (this is grid) and the size of each tile on the tileset.

The tileset looks like a 16x16 so keep that as your cell size, but the tiles have a gap of another 16px between. You will need to set an offset so select the icon with the # and the magnet in the tileset editor

[image]

and Snap Options will appear on your inspector. There you can edit your step, offset, and separation. Mess with that and you will eventually get it right.

[image]

Comment: also note that if you have created atlas entries already, you'll need to remove them (in case tile size was small at the beginning, lots were created). No real harm except many errors in the debugger otherwise. To do so, just check the yellow warning in the tileset tab, which tells to just hit the 33 dots button and remove inexisting tiles.